# scroll to the row in tableview then flashing the row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to scroll to the row and flashing the row by changing the background color.
I can scroll to the row. and i use the method `cellForRow(at:)` to get the cell for later modification and animation. but the `cell` is nil. I don't understand why it is nil as I can scroll to the row with the same `indexPath`.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) // return nil.
if let cell = cell { // nil
// animation here.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, `cellForRow(at: indexPath)` returns:

> An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

At the moment when you call `cellForRow(at: indexPath)` your cell is not visible yet because the animated scrolling hasn't finished yet.

To track the scrolling animation completion you have to implement `UITableViewDelegate` protocol:

```
class YourVC : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ... your code
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathToAnimate) // returns your cell object
        if let cell = cell {
            // animation here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get a nil value if the cell is not visible. Generally cell animations are performed in the tableview delegate `willDisplay cell`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

This is code to animate the cells from the left side when the cells appear. You can modify and perform your required animations by checking at what indexpath you need to perform the animation at.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
    CATransform3D rotation;
    rotation = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 0);


    //2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];

    cell.layer.transform = rotation;
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0);


    //3. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
    let rotation = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 0)

    //2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.transform = rotation
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)

    //3. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
    UIView.beginAnimations("rotation", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.7)
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```